# balancing user-friendliness with the amount of parameters that are required

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, authorize.net

Authorize.NET exposes a [rich API.](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html)

Their first code example, shows how to charge a credit card:

```
﻿using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AuthorizeNet.Api.Controllers;
using AuthorizeNet.Api.Contracts.V1;
using AuthorizeNet.Api.Controllers.Bases;

namespace net.authorize.sample
{
    public class ChargeCreditCard
    {
        public static ANetApiResponse Run(String ApiLoginID, String ApiTransactionKey, decimal amount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Charge Credit Card Sample");

            ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX;

            // define the merchant information (authentication / transaction id)
            ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()
            {
                name = ApiLoginID,
                ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,
                Item = ApiTransactionKey,
            };

            var creditCard = new creditCardType
            {
                cardNumber = "4111111111111111",
                expirationDate = "0718",
                cardCode = "123"
            };

            var billingAddress = new customerAddressType
            {
                firstName = "John",
                lastName = "Doe",
                address = "123 My St",
                city = "OurTown",
                zip = "98004"
            };

            //standard api call to retrieve response
            var paymentType = new paymentType { Item = creditCard };

            // Add line Items
            var lineItems = new lineItemType[2];
            lineItems[0] = new lineItemType { itemId = "1", name = "t-shirt", quantity = 2, unitPrice = new Decimal(15.00) };
            lineItems[1] = new lineItemType { itemId = "2", name = "snowboard", quantity = 1, unitPrice = new Decimal(450.00) };

            var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType
            {
                transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),    // charge the card

                amount = amount,
                payment = paymentType,
                billTo = billingAddress,
                lineItems = lineItems
            };

            var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };

            // instantiate the contoller that will call the service
            var controller = new createTransactionController(request);
            controller.Execute();

            // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)
            var response = controller.GetApiResponse();

            //validate
            if (response != null)
            {
                if (response.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)
                {
                    if(response.transactionResponse.messages != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully created transaction with Transaction ID: " + response.transactionResponse.transId);
                        Console.WriteLine("Response Code: " + response.transactionResponse.responseCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message Code: " + response.transactionResponse.messages[0].code);
                        Console.WriteLine("Description: " + response.transactionResponse.messages[0].description);
                        Console.WriteLine("Success, Auth Code : " + response.transactionResponse.authCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed Transaction.");
                        if (response.transactionResponse.errors != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorCode);
                            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed Transaction.");
                    if (response.transactionResponse != null && response.transactionResponse.errors != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + response.messages.message[0].code);
                        Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + response.messages.message[0].text);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null Response.");
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

If we were to expose this functionality through our own API, it would be something like:

```
public class ChargeCreditCardController:ApiController
{
      public IHttpActionResult Go (String ApiLoginID, String ApiTransactionKey, decimal amount, OpaqueDataType odt, customerAddressType cat, creditCardType cct, etc)
     {
         return ChargeCreditCard.Run(/*pass all params here*/);
     }
}
```

**Without having to make multiple calls, how can we expose this functionality requiring less parameters?**

Comment: Pass in a class with the required properties, and if it's an API you should be POSTing it as JSON.

Comment: how would my implementation change regarding posting as json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how your app can know this information without passing it in as parameters/making more than one call.

You can move some of the information from parameters into headers. e.g. the params: ApiLoginID, ApiTransactionKey

You could also make the parameters implicit by a resource identifier.  In other words you can store some of the information in a database, then reference the information by id.  e.g. Instead of passing in an big model (customerAddressType cat) you could just pass in Id of the information.  This would leave you with one call with less parameters, but would require information to be stored in a Database.

Comment: interesting point! i'd like the service to be stateless, therefore i think i might need all params.

Comment: furthermore if some of this information needs to be encrypted, for example the login and transactionkey, how would my implementation change? i'm not sure how to go about this

Comment: If the API needs to be stateless I'd say either headers or parameters are your only real option. In terms of encryption I believe the whole HTTP request is encrypted under SSL (even headers).